# Printing out duplicate items from nested list

Tags: python, list, function, nested-lists, python-3.9

The system asks the user to enter the name of a sweet. If that sweet does not exist in the list it should inform the user. If that sweet is in the list, the list prints out all details of the list each time that particular sweet is mentioned in the list. For example if i input Cadbury:

```
# List of transactions [[customer, sweet, amount, money, day, month]
lst_sweets = [
    ["Tom", "Cadbury", 2, 9, 1, 10],
    ["Rachel", "Galaxy", 5, 10, 1, 9],
    ["Rachel", "Smarties", 4, 10, 1, 8],
    ["Lisa", "Gum drops", 10, 9, 1, 7],
    ["Donald", "Cadbury", 1, 5, 1, 6],
    ["Marie", "Smarties", 5, 10, 1, 5]
]
def sweet_purchases():
    x = input("Enter the sweet name")

    p = -1
    sum = 0

    for i in range(len(lst_sweets)):

        item = lst_sweets[i]
        name = item[1]

        if name == x:
            p = i

    if p == -1:
        print("customer not in list")
    else:

        sweetx = lst_sweets[p]
        print("Name:", sweetx[0], "Sweet:", sweetx[1], "amount:", sweetx[2], "money:", sweetx[3], "day:", sweetx[4], "month:", sweetx[5])
```

desired output:
Name:, Tom, Sweet:, Cadbury, amount:, 2, money:, 9, day:, 1, month:, 10
Name:, Donald, Sweet:, Cadbury, amount:, 1, money:, 5, day:, 1, month:, 6

actual output:
Name:, Tom, Sweet:, Cadbury, amount:, 2, money:, 9, day:, 1, month:, 10

Does anyone know why it isn't printing out both? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you find multiple matches, you overwrite `p`, leaving you to only print one match. You should print in the loop:

```py
lst_sweets = [
    ["Tom", "Cadbury", 2, 9, 1, 10],
    ["Rachel", "Galaxy", 5, 10, 1, 9],
    ["Rachel", "Smarties", 4, 10, 1, 8],
    ["Lisa", "Gum drops", 10, 9, 1, 7],
    ["Donald", "Cadbury", 1, 5, 1, 6],
    ["Marie", "Smarties", 5, 10, 1, 5]
]

fields = ["name", "sweet", "amount", "money", "day", "month"]

x = input("Enter the sweet name: ")
found = False
for sweet in lst_sweets:
    if sweet[1] == x:
        found = True
        print(", ".join(f"{field}: {val}" for field, val in zip(fields, sweet)))
if not found:
    print("sweet not found")
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are setting `p` on each loop is clearing the previous match.

```
def sweet_purchases():
  x = input("Enter the sweet name")
  cnt=0
  for entry in lst_sweets:
    if entry[1] == x:
      print(entry) # or whatever
      cmt+=1
  if not cmt:
    print('No joy')
```

This is the simplest way if you just want to print some output. If you want to do something after you find all the rows you'll need to accumulate the results. Something like this:

```
def sweet_purchases():
  x = input("Enter the sweet name")
  hits=[]
  for entry in lst_sweets:
    if entry[1] == x:
      hits.append(entry)
   return hits
```

But the "pythonic" way to just find the list without proceesing them would be to use a comprehension:

```
def sweet_purchases():
  x = input("Enter the sweet name")
  return [e for e in lst_sweets
            if e[1] == x]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# List of transactions [[customer, sweet, amount, money, day, month]
lst_sweets = [
    ["Tom", "Cadbury", 2, 9, 1, 10],
    ["Rachel", "Galaxy", 5, 10, 1, 9],
    ["Rachel", "Smarties", 4, 10, 1, 8],
    ["Lisa", "Gum drops", 10, 9, 1, 7],
    ["Donald", "Cadbury", 1, 5, 1, 6],
    ["Marie", "Smarties", 5, 10, 1, 5]
]
def sweet_purchases():
    x = input("Enter the sweet name")

    p = [] # make a list that stores the matching index
    sum = 0

    for i in range(len(lst_sweets)):

        item = lst_sweets[i]
        name = item[1]

        if name == x:
            p.append(i)

    if p == None: # if the list is empty
        print("customer not in list")
    else:
        # Now iterate over the correct list of index and print the values
        for i in p:
            sweetx = lst_sweets[i]
            print("Name:", sweetx[0], "Sweet:", sweetx[1], "amount:", sweetx[2], "money:", sweetx[3], "day:", sweetx[4], "month:", sweetx[5])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop only results in a single match.  A more accurate (and simpler!) way of doing this is to use a list comprehension to produce a filtered version of the original list, and then iterate over the filtered list:

```
def sweet_purchases():
    sweet = input("Enter the sweet name")
    filtered_entries = [entry for entry in lst_sweets if entry[1] == sweet]
    if not filtered_entries:
        print("customer not in list")
        return
    for entry in filtered_entries:
        [name, sweet, amount, money, day, month] = entry
        print(f"Name: {name} Sweet: {sweet} amount: {amount} money: {money} day: {day} month: {month}")
```